# React Native: Issue with Fetch API - Unable to Retrieve Data from Server

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm facing an issue with fetching data from a server in my React Native project. I've been using the Fetch API to make a simple GET request, but I'm unable to retrieve the data. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Data:', data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  }

  return (
    // My component JSX here
  );
}
```

I've confirmed that the API endpoint is accessible and returns valid JSON when accessed through a browser or tools like Postman. However, when I run this code in my React Native app, the **`data`** variable remains undefined, and I don't see any errors in the console.

Could someone please review my code and suggest potential reasons why the Fetch API might not be working as expected in a React Native environment? Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the postman get request that worked with the URL used in there?

Comment: It is a good practice to check response.ok before proceeding to parse data. Also response.status and response.statusText might give you an idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the header info:

```
 const response = await fetch(`https://api.example.com/data`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    const resData = await response.json()
```